# Creating a Facebook HTML page

Tags: html, facebook

I want to create a static Facebook page, which should include some images and text. Are there any restrictions to what I can use? Ideally I'd simply thrown in my HTML markup, with images , styles and fonts hosted on another domain and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just images and text there won't be any problem but be aware that Facebook saves to cache the styles if you use the <link> tag and you won't see the changes you make on it right away.